# Python too many values to unpack

Tags: python, tuples

so I want to find distance between two xyz file coordinate using python, 
I was given this for example
0.215822, -1.395942, -1.976109
0.648518, -0.493053, -2.101929
In python, I wrote,

```
f = open('First_Ten_phenolMeNH3+.txt', 'r')
lines = f.readlines()
a = lines[0] #(0.215822, -1.395942, -1.976109)
(x1,y1,z1) = a
b = lines[1] #(0.648518, -0.493053, -2.101929)
(x2,y2,z2) = b

distance = math.sqrt((x1-x2)**2 + (y1-y2)**2 + (z1-z2)**2)
print(distance)


f.close()
```

I want to use tuple unpacking and to calucalte distance, however, I keep getting too many values to unpack (expected 3), I think it is because of the txt file, Is there any better way I can do it ?? The problem is i need have 5000 coordinate file to sort through, so it will be inefficient to plug in coordinate one by one.

Thank you

Comment: try `(x1,y1,z1) = eval(a)`

Comment: Does you file has parenthesis, like `(0.215822, -1.395942, -1.976109)` comment suggest or only `,`-sheared numbers, like description suggest?

Answer (score 1):

You could use this:

```
from scipy.spatial import distance
from ast import literal_eval
a = literal_eval(lines[0]) #(0.215822, -1.395942, -1.976109)
b = literal_eval(lines[1]) #(0.648518, -0.493053, -2.101929)
dst = distance.euclidean(a, b) #1.009091198622305
```

Comment: Isn't using `eval` considered a bad practice due to safety issues?

Comment: due to safety issues, yes, for sure. if you could expect some injection in that file. dont do this. @MichailHighkhan i edited my answer

Answer (score 0):

you are trying to assign a string to a tuple. try using split() first:

```
a = lines[0].split() #(0.215822, -1.395942, -1.976109)
(x1,y1,z1) = a
```

also, this will put strings into x1,x2,x3, you need to convert them to float:

```
x1 = float(x1)
x2 = float(x2)
x3 = float(x3)
```

Answer (score 0):

`line[0]` is a string, as it in a text file. You need to convert it into tuple of floats

```
x1, y1, z1 = (float(value) for value in line[1:-1].split(', '))
```